# Term for implying something is free only to then charge someone for taking it

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term or expression for when something was implied to be free, only to then be charged for once accepted.

I have seen street vendors do this a lot. I watched as a gyro vendor complimented a young tourist. The teenager acknowledge the vendor's compliment. The vendor then offered him and his friends gyros, they were seemingly free due to the vendor being impressed. Once the gyros had been served, the vendor charged the teenager for the gyros. Looking embarrassed, he paid him.

I have always wondered if there is a term for this, even a legal one.

Answer (score 1):

```
*caveat emptor* would be my pick.
```

the old saying `beware of Greeks bearing gifts` doesn't quite work, even though Gyros were involved.  Politeness can be confused as free.  If you go into a restaurant and the owner says "Would you like a steak?"  There would certainly not be the expectation of free food, unless "on the house were added". "Bait and switch" as a legal term almost works, but not quite.

Comment: In the computer biz that's "Beware of geeks bearing grifts."

Answer (score 1):

In US English there is a slang term "Indian Giver"  that is the term for when someone offers you something for a very affordable price and later wants it back. Like when I got a Free Second Opinion from Dr On Demand and then they changed me 50 bucks 3-5 months later and the billing department said that I was trying to make them laugh, they said that nobody gets out alive for free because this land and everyone souls in it belong to an increasingly capitalistic private government made up of corporate lackeys who refuse to stand for justice and have run out economy very inefficiently and who try to cover it up with subsidies in turn raising taxes and prices on goods & services. Perhaps they should use the less racially charged expression "android giver" for when someone doesn't know or doesn't care to read the Terms Of Service and ends up 1000 dollars in debt with nothing tangible to show for it.

Comment: You should probably chop out the political rant in the middle since this isn't a site for discussion of politics or economics.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of *misleading / aggressive selling*.

From a [Which? article of 2014](https://www.which.co.uk/news/2014/10/new-consumer-protection-against-misleading-sales-381078/) by Eleanor Snow:

> New consumer protection against misleading sales
>
> *Financial redress for underhand and aggressive selling*
>
> Consumers now have greater rights to financial redress if they are the victims of misleading actions or aggressive sales tactics. The
> new rules come into force today and have been made to the Consumer
> Protection from Unfair Trading Regulations.  The regulations make it
> clear that traders are not allowed to use misleading, underhand or
> aggressive tactics to get you to part with your cash.